# How can I make a JPA entity append only where the composite key includes a timestamp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, java-17

I have a database where the primary key is a composite key which is composed of a varchar and a timestamp. Each time an entity is modified or inserted, a new entry is added to the database.

How can I model this with a JPA repository? This is what I have right now.

Relevant parts of entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions", schema = "auth")
@IdClass(PermissionId.class)
public class Permission implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "permissionid")
  private String permissionId;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "createdat")
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private Instant createdAt;
...
}
```

ID class:

```
public class PermissionId implements Serializable {
    private String permissionId;
    private Instant createdAt;
}
```

When I create a new entity, I get an error saying that createdAt cannot be null. How can I achieve my desired behavior? I cannot change the database schema.

**Edit**

I found a workaround

```
@Query(
        value = "INSERT INTO auth.permissions (permissionID, createdAt,...) VALUES (:permissionID, NOW(), ...)",
        nativeQuery = true
)
@Modifying
recordPermission(String permissionID, ...);
```

This works, but I'm still interested in knowing if there is a "correct " way to do it.

Comment: I would try to add a second annotation @CreationTimestamp

Comment: Another way is to add a `@PrePersist` listener that fills in `createdAt`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos That worked! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mar-Z You cannot have `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` on the same variable. Having just `@CreationTimestamp` does not get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic and JPA-standard way to modify the content of an entity in response to its storage operations (create, update, read, delete) is the mechanism of Entity Listeners, described in ch 3.5 of the JPA 2.1 specification. For this case specifically, the `@PrePersist` listener method, that JPA calls just before persisting an entity (creating/inserting the DB records).

You can place the listener in the entity class itself, e.g.:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions", schema = "auth")
@IdClass(PermissionId.class)
public class Permission implements Serializable {
  ...

  @Id
  @Column(name = "createdat")
  private Instant createdAt;

  @PrePersist
  void prePersist() {
    this.createdAt = Instant.now();
  }

  ...
}
```

Or in a different class like:

```java
public class PermissionEntityListener {
  @PrePersist
  void prePersist(Permission entity) { // method name can be anything
    entity.setCreatedAt(Instant.now());
  }
}
```

If the listener is in a separate class, you have to activate it either with an annotation in the entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions", schema = "auth")
@IdClass(PermissionId.class)
@EntityListeners(PermissionEntityListener.class) // <----- HERE
public class Permission implements Serializable {
  ...
}
```

Or in the XML descriptor, `META-INF/orm.xml`:

```xml
<entity-mappings>
  ...
  <entity-listeners><!-- can be found at different places, please check specs -->
    <entity-listener class="com.yourpackage.PermissionEntityListener">
      <pre-persist method-name="prePersist" />
    </entity-listener>
  </entity-listeners>
  ...
</entity-mappings>
```

There are lots of information online and in the specs for the Entity Listeners.